# Как перенести свой проект на gulp 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

В общем, насмотревшись видеоуроков по Node.js, я решил сделать что-то своё. Но проблема-то в том, что у меня Gulp 4, а код из gulpfile.js написан на 3-ем.

Вопрос: как его подогнать под версию 4?

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');


gulp.task('sass', function() {

    return gulp.src('[/public/sass/**/*.sass', '/public/sass/**/*.scss]')
              .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError))// Преобразуем Sass в CSS посредством gulp-sass
              .pipe(gulp.dest ('public/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(['public/sass/**/*.sass', 'public/sass/**/*.scss'], ['sass']);
});
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переделал ваш конфиг под формат Gulp 4, по комментариям должно быть понятно.

```
"use strict";

/**
 * Gulpfile для Gulp 4
 */

const { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

// Функции для заданий
function sassTask() {
    return src('[/public/sass/**/*.sass', '/public/sass/**/*.scss]')
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(dest('public/css'));
}

function watchTask() {
    watch(['public/sass/**/*.sass', 'public/sass/**/*.scss'], parallel(sassTask));
}

// Задания
exports.sass = series(
    sassTask
);

exports.watch = series(
    watchTask
);

exports.default = series(
    watchTask
);
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!)) Как всё сложно блин с этим 4ым Gulp)

Comment: Рад был помочь!) Отметьте мой ответ решением, пожалуйста.